# How do i register UserManager with OWIN context?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin, owin-middleware

When I create MVC 5 application in Visual Studio 2013, and choose Individual accounts as authentication then scaffolding automatically configures ASP Net Identity. It creates several classes along with `ApplicationDbContext` and `ApplicationUserManager`.  It also registers these classes with OWIN context as below to use single instance per request.

```
 public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
 {
        // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

 }
```

basically it registers `static Create` method of each class. This static method is responsible for creating instance of that class.

**Quesion**
1>If I don't want to use static create method, is the approach below correct?.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string, IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(string connString)
        : base(connString)
    {
    }
}

public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
   var conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Myconnection"].ConnectionString
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(()=>new ApplicationDbContext(conString));
}
```

2> How do I register `ApplicationUserManager` without using the static Create method. (It must set UserValidator,PasswordValidator, UserTokenProvider etc)
Should I set Validators and UserTokenProvider in `ApplicationUserManager`'s constructor? Like below

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser, string>
{
     public ApplicationUserManager(ApplicationUserStore store)
        : base(store)
    {
        base.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };

        // Configure validation logic for passwords
        base.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true,
        };

        base.EmailService = new EmailService();

        //?????????How do I get options.DataProtectionProvider ??????
        var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            base.UserTokenProvider = 
                new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
        }
  }
```

3>In approach above How do I register `ApplicationUserManager` with OWIN context so that it create single instance per request? `'ApplicationUserManager` also requires `ApplicationUserStore` and `ApplicationDbContext`..how do I pass those to `ApplicationUserManager`'s constructor?